# How to make whole web page pale yellow for reading mode?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add a feature to my website, where users may have a **toggle button** for **reading mode**. When that toggle button will be clicked the whole page will become **pale yellow** color and hence **reducing Ultra Violet** rays coming out of the screen so that users have less strain to their eyes while reading.

For this, I am using overlays like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay" class='visibility-hidden' style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 
100%;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;background-color: rgba(255, 210, 124, 0.21);z-index: 1;"></div>

<button class='read_mode'>Click here For Read mode</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.visibility-hidden{
  display:none;
}

.visibility-true{
  display:block;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.read_mode').click(function(){
alert("Now you can NOT click the button");
$("#overlay").removeClass("visibility-hidden").addClass("visibility-true");

});
```

The problem in this approach is that the buttons and other elements on the web page can not be clicked any more because `<div>` is not clickable because this `<div>` with pale yellow color is above all other elements on the web page.

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aeok8sbp/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `#overlay` CSS. Doing that, it will ignore touch and click events. Example on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frangaren/2ynsoe1u/2/) (it doesn't toggle because you haven't implemented that but the button registers the click and shows the alert).